# Direct insert into M_Product_Org Table

Tags: openbravo

I am not very much familiar with Java. I plan to do insert data in the M_Product_Org table from back-end but I noticed that M_Product_Org_ID is unique encrypted key generated by Openbravo application.

Like to know if there are is a way to generate M_Product_Org_ID?

Answer (score 0):

**get_uuid()** - function can be used to generate the UUID for the primary key column.

I have tried to insert a record for c_file table using **PG_Admin GUI.**

```
INSERT INTO c_file(
        c_file_id, ad_client_id, ad_org_id, isactive, created, createdby, 
        updated, updatedby, "name", c_datatype_id, seqno, "text", ad_table_id, 
        ad_record_id)
VALUES (get_uuid(), '23C59575B9CF467C9620760EB255B389', '0', 'Y', '2013-08-28 19:43:59.456', '100', 
        '2013-08-28 19:43:59.456', '100', 'vel', get_uuid(), 20, '  test ', '100', 
        '99674771BFD840F0965FFCABD493CBC5');
```

This would insert a new record into the c_file table provided all the foreign key constraints are met.

Comment: Many thanks.trying to modify the same in ProductsProcess.java in IDL module. Can you pl help me on this.
    ProductOrg productOrg = findDALInstance(false, ProductOrg.class, new Value(
      "organization", Organization,"product", product));
 if (productOrg == null) {
 ProductOrg proOrg =  OBProvider.getInstance().get(ProductOrg.class);
 proOrg.setActive(true);
 proOrg.setOrganization(rowOrganization); 
 proOrg.setProduct(product);
 proOrg.setStorageBin("DEFAULT");
 } else {
proOrg.setCapacity (100);
proOrg.setMinimumLeadTime(1);
}
OBDal.getInstance().save(proOrg);
OBDal.getInstance().flush();